# PostgreSQL Crosstab Select Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

Does any one know how to create crosstab queries in PostgreSQL?
For example I have two following tables:

TABLE A

```
| ID 1       | ID 2        | ID 3         | 
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| 00001      |        01   |    0001      |
| 00001      |        02   |    0001      |  
| 00001      |        01   |    0002      |
```

TABLE B

```
| ID 1       | ID 2        | ID 3         | price        | tax_rate     |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|:------------:|:------------:|
| 00001      |        01   |    0001      |5000          | 8            |
| 00001      |        01   |    0001      |6000          | 10           |
```

I would like the query to return the following crosstab:

```
| ID 1       | ID 2        | ID 3         | price_8      | price_10     |  
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|:------------:|:------------:| 
| 00001      |        01   |    0001      |5000          | 6000         | 
| 00001      |        02   |    0001      |null          | null         |
| 00001      |        01   |    0002      |null          | null         |
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Check the doc https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
       'SELECT A.ID1, A.ID2, A.ID3, B.PRICE, B.TAX_RATE 
        FROM A
        LEFT JOIN B
        ON A.ID1 = B.ID1
        AND A.ID2 = B.ID2
        AND A.ID3 = B.ID3') AS
FINAL_RESULT (ID1 TEXT, ID2 TEXT, ID3 TEXT, PRICE_8 NUMERIC, PRICE_9 NUMERIC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample for your tables:

```
SELECT split_part(id, '.', 1) AS id1,
split_part(id, '.', 2) AS id2,
split_part(id, '.', 3) AS id3,
price_8, price_10
FROM crosstab(
  'select id1||''.''||id2||''.''||id3 as id, cast(tax_rate as text) as taxRate, price 
   from (select * from Table1 natural left join Table2
   order by 1,2,3) t'
   )   
AS ct (
  id text, 
  price_8 int,
  price_10 int
  );
```